# Unexpected token error on a simple for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I was working on a simple problem on a site, to write a function which returns the sum of all the members of an array.

```
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0, i <= ar.length - 1, i++) {
        sum += ar[i];
        i++;    
    }
    return sum;
}
```

and I'm getting this:

```
    for (i = 0, i <= ar.length - 1, i++) {
                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at checkScriptSyntax (internal/bootstrap/node.js:617:5)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:280:11)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Replace your commas with semicolons: `for (i = 0; i <= ar.length - 1; i++)` or the more common form, `for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for for the correct syntax for `for` loops.

Comment: Declaring a for loop always requires three sections seperated with a semicolon, these three sections are missing, and the engine notices that when it arrives at the closing ) ...

Comment: Flagging to close due to syntax issues which are not helpful for future readers

Comment: @JonasWilms ***Declaring a for loop always requires three sections seperated with a semicolon*** << Not true. [You don't have to supply anything in the parenthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Using_for_without_a_statement), but if you do, and there is more than one configuration, then semi-colons are required to separate them.

Comment: Such a rookie mistake. Now I feel bad for posting this question on the site.

Comment: @scott what? the link youve provided does not say that at all. `for()` is a syntax error. `for(;;)` isnt.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: You always need three sections but they can be empty.

Comment: @FelixKling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Using_for_without_a_statement

Comment: @ScottMarcus: and it shows that semicolons are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One: Use semicolons `;` not commas `,`. Two, your loop will run one time too many - change `<=` to `<`, and remove the `i++` inside the loop body:

```js
var ar = [1, 2, 3];
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  sum += ar[i];
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your commas to semicolons (simple mistake I make all the time)

```
var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= ar.length - 1; i++) {
        sum += ar[i];
        i++;    
    }
    return sum;
```

Comment: Use a better linter.